# Add 'application.errorChannel' to config in Spring Integration

Tags: java, error-handling, spring-integration, solace

I have written a program to read messages from a Solace queue. I am getting the below error.

Can you please help?

[image]
**Code given below:**

My main config is given below:

```
public class ReadFromQueueConfig {

    @Autowired
    private PrintMessageFromQueue printMessageFromQueue;

    String queueName = "MY.SAMPLE.SOLACE.QUEUE";

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        try {
            SolConnectionFactory scf = SolJmsUtility.createConnectionFactory();
            scf.setHost("host");
            scf.setUsername("username");
            scf.setVPN("vpm");
            scf.setPassword("password");
            scf.setDirectTransport(false);

            ccf.setTargetConnectionFactory(scf);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
        return ccf;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow handleJsmInput() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.inboundAdapter(jmsConnectionFactory()).destination(queueName))
                        .handle(printMessageFromQueue)
                        .get();
    }
}
```

**PrintMessageFromQueue.java:**
[image]

UPDATE:
My main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class TestReadFromQueueApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestReadFromQueueApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't show what is the problem really. What we see with your logs is a normal application start and stop. Nothing more. You might just close an application context too early in the `main()`. You should consider to add some `sleep()` or reaction to end-user input before closing an application context.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. What I really want is for the program to keep listening on the queue, and print whatever message is being posted to it. What should I add to keep the program running and listening to messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in the `main()` after creating an `ApplicationContext`:

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
context.close();
```

So, you application is not going to exit until some input from the console.

Also you can wait for the messages to be consumed, e.g. via the `QueueChannel.receive()`.
Some sample to block a `main` in done in the Apache Kafka sample in the Spring Integration Samples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/kafka/Application.java

Comment: Hi Artem, it is a spring boot application, and I do not want to use ApplicationContext. I have updated the question with the main class I have used. What should I fix to get the program to listen to messages on the Solace queue and print them?

Comment: I am getting the same issue (context shuts down before messages are read from the queue) when I use this main class.

Comment: Huh? The ` SpringApplication.run()` creates exactly an `ApplicationContext`. As I said: you need to delay an exit from the `main()` somehow and I suggested you to wait for some input from the console.